# how to sent mail from my Ubuntu server

Tags: server, postfix, mail

I am a beginner in mail server. I want to set up my own mail server so that I can send mail from my server to anyone. I have also installed postfix.

- How do I set this up?
- What do I need?
- How do I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to send mails from your server, you don't need to install your own mail server, you can send emails by SMTP. For this you can try `ssmtp` (Simple SMTP). More details here: http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-ssmtp.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing so is very easy.

Follow this walkthrough: [Install and Setup Postfix on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-12-04)

To send email, you can also:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mailutils

mail -s "Subject" -t contact@mail.com
```